# Mongoose validating embedded

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I created the following schema (coffeescript):

```
user_schema = new app.db.schema(
    username: String
    email: String
    password: String
    account:
        plan:
            type: String
            default: "Free"
            enum: ["Free", "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold"]
        comments: [
            title: String
            message: String
            date_added: Date
        ]
)
```

I could have probably created 2 more schemas here (account and comment) but I know each user has one account associated and each account has maximum 100 comments so I like the idea of having it all inside a single document. It's not making sense I know (user/account/comments) but I'm just familiarizing myself to noSql and rich documents so it's just a test.

My question is about saving a new comment for a given account and validating them. I can validate a user email by doing this (which works btw):

```
user_schema.path("email").validate((value, respond)->
    respond v.check(value).isEmail()
, "Invalid email address")
```

...but how would I validate a comment? How do I save a new comment under a given user.account.comments array? Comments are not required by default but if a new comment is added I want to validate that the title and message is required let's say.

Is this type of nesting normal or I have to create separate models and reference them? I read a lot about embedding vs linking and I feel like this would make for an embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the validation attributes right in the schema definition of the embedded object:

```
comments: [
    title:
        type: String
        required: true
    message: 
        type: String
        required: true
    date_added: Date
]
```